# php date function, for previous/next day

Tags: php, html, date

Is there any simple way to show previous and next days with the date function in php

```
<?php
echo date ("M m, l")
?>
```

for example

That'd just display Sep 09, Monday

however is there any way to have it so with the click of a button (next) it'd show sep 10, tuesday?

Comment: you would have to reload the page if you want PHP to do it for you.  Are you looking for just "yesterday" and "tomorrow"? or want to repeatedly click next/prev to keep getting different dates?

Comment: can you show us what you tried?

Comment: has been answered a gazillion times before. Please use the search function before asking questions.

Comment: they don't call me uneducated guy for nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into [DateTime relative formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
$date->modify('tomorrow');
echo $date->format('M m, l');

$date->modify('yesterday');
echo $date->format('M m, l');
?>
```

Comment: Or directly:
$dateTime = new DateTime('yesterday');
Or
$dateTime = new DateTime('-2 days'); 
Or 
$dateTime = new DateTime('-10 years');
Or 
$dateTime = new DateTime('+2 months')

Comment: Such a simple explanation, thank you. The important aspect in John's answer is that you're be able to set the date manually, which @CappY seems to forget in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mktime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mktime.php) function:

`echo date ("M m, l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 10, 2012))`

From [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) manual page:

```
$tomorrow  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"));
$lastmonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"),   date("Y"));
$nextyear  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),   date("d"),   date("Y")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one may help for displaying the next day:

```
<?php
$tomorrow = time() + (24 * 60 * 60); // current time + 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds
echo 'Tomorrow: '. date('M m, l', $nextWeek) ."\n";
?>
```

Or `time() - (24 * 60 * 60)` for yesterday.

Comment: PHP Manual advises against directly adding seconds: "This can be more reliable than simply adding or subtracting the number of seconds in a day or month to a timestamp because of daylight saving time."

Comment: Oh .. didn't think about that :/

Answer (score 0):

You could use strtotime to add times

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' +1 day'))
```

The above would add 1 day to the currrent date....

look at this for more info 
http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/php-adding-and-subtracting-dates/

Answer (score 0):

```
date('M m,l',strtotime('+1 day'))
date('M m,l',strtotime('-1 day'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $cd = strtotime(date ("M m, l"));
 $mth = 1; // adding 1 day with the current date
 $retDAY = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,date('m',$cd)+$mth,date('d',$cd),date('Y',$cd))); 
echo $retDAY ; // Output 2012-10-10
```

Check [THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php) page, have lots of example like the above one which can give a clear idea about the said function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tomorrow  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"));
$tomorrow = date("F j, l",$tomorrow); 
$yesterday=mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")-1, date("Y"));
$yesterday=date("F j, l",$yesterday);
echo $tomorrow; 
echo $yesterday;
```